# Can I make source and sink for water?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Can I make a source (where water comes from) and a sink (where water goes or sits) in water simulation?
I want to make fountain so that when it is full, the water overflows from it.

How can I make a sink for it, or I control the incoming and outgoing flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can. The "sink" is called outflow, look for "Outflow" in the fluid sim. And the outflow mesh stops water from overflowing.